# How to Autoplay youTube Video in HTML iframe in iphone

Tags: javascript, html, iphone, iframe, youtube

I am storing some YouTube Links in IFrame and some other Links like Vimeo,DailyMotion videos and this all videos showed be auto played when we hit URL .

Problem : Vimeo and dailyMotion videos are getting Auto played but Only YouTube Video is not getting Auto played .

How can we solve this problem, can we use JavaScript to achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: As far as i know YouTube video's can't autoplay in UIWebviews anymore for a while ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, at the end of the youtube url add ?autoplay=1. example http://www.youtube.com/v/jdsnjksd_ds?autoplay=1